# Stop event propagation from jquery Draggable stop to onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a draggable div , made dragable with jqueryUI draggable library.  I have an onclick handler on the div, but when I drag the div it then fires the click handler, which I don't want. The drag stop happens before the click, so I tried this:

```
$("#div").draggable({
    stop: function(e) {
        e.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

but the onclick event still fires.  Any ideas JavaScript gurus?

Comment: Have you tried using `preventDefault()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use chaining and handle it directly on the click method. 
While in the dragging state, [the draggable gets a new class: `ui-draggable-dragging`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/).

```
$("#div")
    .draggable()
    .click(function(){
      if ( $(this).is('.ui-draggable-dragging') ) {
            return;
      }
      // click action here
    });
```